# npm start works on C: drive but not E: drive

Tags: node-modules, npm-start

I have a repo for a project I am working on, when I clone the repo into my E: drive and try to do **npm start**, I get errors. However, when I clone the repo into my C: drive, it works flawlessly.

Here are the errors I am getting on my E: drive:

```
Failed to compile.

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
Require stack:
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
asset static/js/bundle.js 48.5 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 9.19 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 27.1 KiB [cached] 9 modules
modules with errors 117 bytes [errors]
  ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
  ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
  ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/src/index.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/src/index.js
Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
Require stack:
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:178:10)
    at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:189:18
    at handleResult (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:53:2)
    at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:35:10)

ERROR in ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js
Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
Require stack:
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
    at runLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
    at NormalModule.build (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
    at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12

ERROR in ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js
Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
Require stack:
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
    at runLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
    at NormalModule.build (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
    at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12

ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10' in 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client'

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
  ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
      at processResult (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:753:19)
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:855:5
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:185:11
      at loadLoader (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:33:11)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12

  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15

  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27

  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19

  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18

  - loadLoader.js:19 loadLoader
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:19:17

  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2

  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2

  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3

  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15

  - Compilation.js:1369
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12

  - ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../../../#work/Programming Projects/Blockwatch/Client/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):

  - Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'

  - Require stack:

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

  - - E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15

  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27

  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19

  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18

  - loadLoader.js:19 loadLoader
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:19:17

  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2

  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2

  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3

  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15

  - Compilation.js:1369
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12

  - NormalModule.js:753 processResult
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:753:19

  - NormalModule.js:855
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:855:5

  - LoaderRunner.js:399
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11

  - LoaderRunner.js:185
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:185:11

  - loadLoader.js:33 loadLoader
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:33:11

  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2

  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [Client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2

  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3

  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15

  - Compilation.js:1369
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12

  - child-compiler.js:169
    [Client]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18

  - Compiler.js:564
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:564:11

  - Compiler.js:1183
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1183:17


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [Client]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compiler.js:1179
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1179:33

  - Compilation.js:2784 finalCallback
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2784:11

  - Compilation.js:3089
    [Client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:3089:11


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [Client]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14



1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

1 error has detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 6 errors in 1350 ms
```

When it says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js'
```

I go to check if the path exists and it does, so I'm not sure why it fails to find it.

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and running **npm install**
on it but I have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modules and try this, it will install packages globally:

```
 npm install -g
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried this but I am getting errors

Comment: `PS E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client> npm install -g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-17T22_23_37_318Z-debug-0.log
PS E:\#work\Programming Projects\Blockwatch\Client> `